# Matplotlib specify color with a tuple

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, tuples

Matplotlib recognize color in many formats, including as a tuple.  What's wrong with this code? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = []
for _ in xrange(2):
    data.append((np.random.rand(), np.random.rand()))
    data.append((np.random.rand(), np.random.rand()))
#    data.append('b')          # this works
#    data.append('0.5')        # this also works
    color = (0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
    data.append(tuple(color))  # this does not work

plt.plot(*data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should tell us what errors you are experiencing, and what you expect to get out of it. "What's wrong with this code" is a bit arbitrary

Answer (score 3):

you're passing everything as data

so you're plotting this:

```
[
     (0.45, 0.36),
     (0.33, 0.78),
     (0.1,  0.2,  0.3),
]
```

You will get a value error, because your table of data has two values in the first two rows but three values in the third row.

Comment: thank you for the answer.  I understand what may confuse the program as you point out.  However, Matplotlib manual specifies: "Matplotlib recognizes the following formats to specify a color:

an RGB or RGBA tuple of float values in [0, 1] (e.g., (0.1, 0.2, 0.5) or (0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3));
a string representation of a float value in [0, 1] inclusive for gray level (e.g., '0.5');
one of {'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'w'}; among others.  How to make the program aware that a the 'color' is a tuple for color?